# What was the use of the subject Divination?

Tags: harry-potter, divination, sybill-trelawney

Why was divination taught at Hogwarts?

Just for that subject, Dumbledore had to hire a fraud like Sybill Trelawney. I know it was because of her prophecy that Dumbledore and wizarding world knew about Harry Potter and the end of Voldemort, but she wasn't predicting anything real during her time as a teacher (except the one about Dark Lord rising again).

How was divination helping students in Hogwarts?

Comment: Trelawney made a few more accurate predictions than you give her credit for: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124525/how-many-of-trelawneys-prophecies-have-come-true

Comment: In fact, I can't think of a prediction of Trelawney's that _didn't_ ultimately come true in some fashion. Even her random prediction to Umbridge came true in the form of Centaurs.

Comment: Also, Divination wasn't the only subject that taught the art of predicting the future. Look up Arithmancy, the art of predicting the future using numbers, Hermione Granger's favourite subject.

Comment: I have neither voted to close this question, nor given a downvote (in fact, the opposite). This seems like an interesting question, and answerable too. Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95287/what-is-divination-as-practiced-by-wizards-really-like?rq=1

Comment: @DheerajKumar this question is now a Hot Network Question. You can expect quite a bit more votes coming in, likely making up for those few down votes. Enjoy the ride!

Comment: Trelawney was a fraud? That's news to me. What is your evidence for this claim? As far as I remember, all her predictions came true.

Comment: @sgroves: “I see,” said Professor McGonagall, fixing Harry with her beady eyes. “Then you should know, Potter, that Sibyll Trelawney has predicted the death of one student a year since she arrived at this school. None of them has died yet. Seeing death omens is her favorite way of greeting a new class. If it were not for the fact that I never speak ill of my colleagues —”

Comment: @DheerajKumar McGonagall could be lying or exaggerating. We don't know. I believe we do know that all the predictions Trelawney made in the book *did* come true.

Comment: @sgroves see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/124533/19561

Comment: @SQB Right, that answer agrees with what I said.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We have another question about the position of Sybill Trelawney at Hogwarts:

[Did Dumbledore create Divination position just to get the prophet (Sybil) under Hogwarts protection?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/46988/19561)

[Its sole answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/46989/19561) confirms that Dumbledore actually wanted to remove Divination from the curriculum, but kept it just to get and keep Sybill Trelawney at Hogwarts, due to her prophesy regarding Voldemort.

So the students of Hogwarts are still being taught Divination as an excuse to keep  Sybill Trelawny employed and protected at Hogwarts. Presumably, Dumbledore didn't have a high opinion of Divination, but likely considered it harmless.

> I had gone there to see an applicant for the post of Divination teacher, **though it was against my inclination to allow the subject of Divination to continue at all.**
>   <sub>*(Emphasis mine)*</sub>

Comment: that's something i was looking for. Thanks bud. accepting this.

Comment: @DheerajKumar Thanks! Also, don't let a couple of down votes get to you. Remember that one up vote cancels five down votes.